# foreach through a map that has another map as value in Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript

I made a service in Java that returns as observable a map<k, map<k,v>> and I'm attempting to iterate through the outer map with a foreach. I'm struggling to.

```
[...]
.then(
    (response: Package) => {
         response.activityMap.forEach((key: string, value: Map<string, number>) => {
             //do something
         });
    }
)
[...]
```

Package is a type with the following parameters:

```
export interface Package{ 
    diagnostic?: Diagnostic;
    activityMap?: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: number; }; };
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a forEach that iterates through the "father" map, so for each key //dosomething

But it won't let me use foreach:

This expression is not callable.
Type '{ [key: string]: number; }' has no call signatures.

Comment: And what's the actual issue?

Comment: @AldinBradaric it won't let me use a foreach on that:

This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ [key: string]: number; }' has no call signatures.

Comment: Because `activityMap` is defined as an object, which itself cannot be iterated. You'd have to define a structure that is capable of utilizing `forEach`, ie. an array or map (iirc, TS should be able to use maps).

Comment: @AldinBradaric thanks this helped me solve it. it made me figure out that the service was returning an object instead of a map so I went for Object.keys and was able to manage that object as a map.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning an observable, you have to first subscribe to the observable, then you can iterate the returned values.

There are 2 approaches in order how we handle subscriptions

## Approach 1

## Handling subscription inside our component

```
this.myService.getPackage().subscribe((response: Package) => { 
    response.activityMap.forEach((key: string, value: Map<string, number>) => {
             //do something
         });
})
```

Also make sure to unsubscribe as well to prevent your application from having memory leaks.

You can do that with TakeUntill RxJS operator https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

OR

## Approach 2

## Using Async pipe

Instead of subscribing, you can using async pipes which is considered as a best practice
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/

## Tip

Instead of iterating inside the subscription, I would recommend that you use RxJS Map Operator combined inside a Pipe
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map

Comment: I'm currently following this structure:
servicecall(params).toPromise().then( (response) => //do something

which should be a good alternative to .subscribe since I don't really need to keep listening to the service, right?

Comment: Yes, promise is a good alternative to subscribe. You got me confused why you would return observable from the API but thats not the question here..